# Binary fields cannot be selected in join queries

Tags: apex, soql, dml

I am getting the following error when I execute the below code:

> Binary fields cannot be selected in join queries

I Understand that the `Body` returns binary data but I need to fetch the body of the attachment and the `Contact` `Fistname, LastName` in the single query.

```
List<Contact> oldAttachments =
[SELECT Id, FirstName, LastName,
(SELECT Id, ParentId, Body, Name, ContentType, Description FROM Attachments)
FROM Contact WHERE Id  = 'XXXXXXX'];

List<Attachment> newAttachments = new List<Attachment>();
for(Contact c : oldAttachments)
{
  for(Attachment att : c.attachments)
  {
    Attachment newAttach = new Attachment();
    //newAttach  = att.clone(false,false,false,false); 
    newAttach.Body = att.Body;
    newAttach.ContentType = att.ContentType;
    newAttach.Description = att.Description;
    newAttach.Name = att.Name;
    newAttach.ParentId = c.Id;
    newAttach.Id = null;
    newAttachments.add(newAttach); 
  } 
   }
   insert newAttachments;
```

Comment: select contact to map
and then 
SELECT Id, ParentId, Body, Name, ContentType, Description FROM Attachments where ParentId in contactMap.keySet();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can query on Attachment object by keeping ParentType as Contact.

```
    Set<Id> contactIds = new Set<Id>();

    contactIds.add('xxxxxx'); // Collect all Contact Ids

    List<Attachment> attachmentList = [Select Id, Name, ContentType, ParentId, Description, Body from Attachment Where Parent.Type = 'Contact' and ParentID IN: newIds];
    // Retrieve all fields which will be required for Iteration
    System.debug('::'+attachmentList);

    List<Attachment> newAttachments = new List<Attachment>();
    for(Attachment att : attachmentList){
        Attachment newAttach = new Attachment();
        newAttach.Body = att.Body;
        newAttach.ContentType = att.ContentType;
        newAttach.Description = att.Description;
        newAttach.Name = att.Name;
        newAttach.ParentId = att.ParentId;
        newAttachments.add(newAttach); 
    } 
    insert newAttachments;
```

Comment: I think you missed the important part of my question which I'm copying the attachments but in the above example you are just listing all the Attachment, but how to set parentId to setIds ? meaning that you if you look at my code where i'm setting `newAttach.ParentId = c.Id;`

Comment: Earlier you were iterating over the Contact and then Attachments. In above example, you will iterate over the Attachment records, ParentId of attachment be set as ParentId for a new attachment records.